# Curl not working for hellotxt API

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I have my code like this.

```
<?php
$post_vars = array('app_key'=>'my_api_key', 'user_key' => 'my_user_key');
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://hellotxt.com/api/v1/method/user.validate');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_vars);

$content = curl_exec($c);
print_r($content);
curl_close($c);

?>
```

This display a return response as "app key not specified".
But the same works if i post the api key and user key via a form (form-post).
When i submit the api key and user key using a form i get the response as.

```
<rsp status="OK"><nick>testinguser</nick><name>testinguser</name><avatar>       http://hellotxt.com/avatar/testinguser/medium/image.jpg</avatar></rsp>
```

But i could not do with the curl. What went wrong.
Please guide me
Thanks
Haan
(PS:FYI, the api for hellotxt is here. http://hellotxt.com/developers/api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should send an array as post fields, now you are sending a json encoded string

so you should replace this:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{app_key:"my_api_key", user_key:"my_user_key"}');
```

with

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_vars);
```

where

```
$post_vars = array('app_key'=>'my_api_key', 'user_key' => 'my_user_key');
```

**Edit**: also consider the answer Honoki gave.. I voted up because he has a point also, you need to "tell" curl that you plan to send post

Comment: i have edited my code as u told, but the error is same.. check my code above (which i have edited now, is that correct) ??

Comment: @hjaffer2001 as I said in the update added, you should aslo add the line suggested by Honoki; both these things are needed (just just my answer or his)

Comment: no man, i have used ur code, gettin the same error. thanks a lot for ur effort. wat would be the reason for the above issue??

Comment: @hjaffer2001 if they don't require in the documentation you could try removing this line: `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json'));`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9901/discussion-between-hjaffer2001-and-mishu)

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify you want to make a POST request like follows.

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try **removing** this line from your code:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json'));
```